# Can the adjective "inevitable" be used in these cases?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adjectives

I was just wondering whether 'inevitable' can be used in this case:

> If she died, there would inevitable sadness.

I've seen 'inevitable tension' being used before, so would it be right in that case?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic

Comment: Also, your sentence is ungrammatical, with either tension or sadness.

Comment: Do you mean to ask about the sentence "If she died, there would ***be*** inevitable sadness"? I think you left out a word by accident

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using "inevitable" correctly. "Inevitable tension" would suggest that you know beforehand that a circumstance will result in tension (no matter what). Likewise, in "If she died, there would [be] inevitable sadness[.]" (grammatical corrections made), "inevitable sadness" implies that you know beforehand that her death would cause sadness. So I think you understand how to use "inevitable" in this way.